# Active Directory - Export an OU and sub objects

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, export, import

I would like to export a container and everything it contains with **ldifde** tool.

How can I do that, especially if the container is in Namin Context : *Configuration* ?

I want to export and then import this container (and all objects in it) to Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Are you willing to migrate your AD 2003 to 2008? Or do you want to import these objects in another AD?

Comment: I want to migrate a container from an AD 2003 to an AD 2008.

Comment: I mean is you goal to update your AD 2003 domain to an AD 2008 domain?